# Are inversion and multiplicaton open?

Tags: topological-groups

If $G$ is a topological group, are inversion $G \to G$ and multiplication $G\times G \to G$ open mappings? More concretely, I try to show that division of complex numbers
$$\{(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2;\; w \neq 0\} \to \mathbb{C},\; (z,w) \mapsto \tfrac{z}{w}$$
is an open mapping. I want to use this to construct charts on $\mathbb{CP}^1 = (\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{0\})/\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.
I don't know where to begin.

Comment: By the way there's another [open question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200483/complex-projective-line-hausdorff-as-quotient-space) (no pun intended) I'm still very interested in, which is also related to this one. I hope it's okay to advertise a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, open maps. The inversion $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is in fact a homeomorphism, continuous by def. and its inverse is itself.

For the product, if $U,V\subseteq G$ open subsets, then the image of $(U,V)$ under multiplication is the complex product
$$U\cdot V =\{u\cdot v\mid u\in U,v\in V\} =\bigcup_{u\in U}(u\cdot V)$$
is a union of open sets.

Comment: Yes, thanks. And it's so easy, too! Wait a second, isn't $U \cdot V$ open, even if $V$ is _not_ open? That argument should work for that case, too, am I right? Edit: NICE.

Comment: Exactly. For example $U\cdot\{1\} = U$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $O_1$ and $O_2$ two open subsets ot $G$. As the inversion $i$ is an homeorphism and an involution, $i(O_1)=i^{-1}(O_1)$ is open. Denote $m$ the multiplication map. Then $$m(0_1\times O_2)=\bigcup_{y\in O_2}O_1y$$
is open. We deal with the general case using the definition of product topology.